# Mean kinetic energy according to the WKB approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

> Show that in the WKB approximation, the mean kinetic energy $T_{n1}$ in a bound state $\psi_n$ in a potential $V(x)$ is given by
>
> $\langle T_n \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{dE_n}{dn}$

This is a homework problem and I'm having trouble understanding what it's asking.

- What does the notation $T_{n1}$ mean?
- What is the meaning of the expression $\frac{dE_n}{dn}$? Bound states should have discrete spectra.

Could someone provide a clearer statement of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $T_{n1}$ may come from the fact that the mean is also referred to as the "first moment", this is what the number $1$ as a lower label might stand for. For reference, see the [Wikipedia article on moments in mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29).

Regarding the derivative of the Energy: you are supposed to formally take the derivative of some expression with respect to some variable, even if it is a discrete one.